# Code for automatically entering date/time stamp into cell based upon table heading

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel vba workflow to enter data into a table from a data input sheet (inputwks). This would be as follows:

1. Press button, adds a new row to table.
2. Enters time stamp into specific column header name "Date/Time" column. (column M in the code below)
3. Enters input data from inputwks into specific table header name "data record" column. (shown as column 3 in the code below)

I don't want to use column letters or numbers because I may change the order (e.g. date/time may look better to the user in column A instead of M.).

How do I change the code below so the macro will search for "date/Time" columns instead of going to column M and the same for "data record"?

Thank you for any help given.

```
Sub UpdateLogWorksheet()

    'Dim historyWks As Worksheet
    Dim ccarWks As Worksheet
    Dim inputWks As Worksheet

    Dim nextRow As Long
    Dim oCol As Long
    '======================Named range setup=========================
    Dim myCopy As Range
    Dim myTest As Range
    Dim lRsp As Long
    '=====================worksheet name setup=======================
    Set inputWks = Worksheets("Input (Modded)")     
    Set ccarWks = Worksheets("CCAR - VB Template Ver2.0")     
    oCol = 3 
      '===================Copy/paste data commands==================

    Set myCopy = inputWks.Range("inputvalue") 
    With ccarWks 
        nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    End With

    With ccarWks 
       With .Cells(nextRow, "M") 'was "A"
           .Value = Now
           .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss" 'enter date and time stamp in record
       End With

       myCopy.Copy
       .Cells(nextRow, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True 
       Application.CutCopyMode = False

   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps consider using [`Range.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) to find the column in the header row by searching for its text.

Comment: Totally tangential - but is this for [CCAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comprehensive_Capital_Analysis_and_Review)? Because I pity you if it is, hate that stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the response BigBen. No, it's not for that type of CCAR. This is effectively for collation of issues. I will look into what you've suggested and see if I can make it work.

Comment: Great, please feel free to ask another question as needed if you can't get it to work.

Comment: You could use a named range and get its column with Range("name").Column. This would also make it possible to change the heading title without affecting the macro.

Comment: The answer was to use:

datetimecol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("date/time", ccarWks.Range("A4:AZ4"), 0)

This worked wonderfully in the:

      With ccarWks '*****new version******
       With .Cells(nextRow, datetimecol) 'was "A"
              .Value = Now
           .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss" 'enter date and time stamp in record
        End With

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this code to ensure it was able to dynamically change the column number it was looking for:

```
   Datetimecol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("date/time", CCARWKS.Range("A4:AZ4"), 0)

   With .Cells(nextRow, datetimecol)
```

This now changes the column value automatically and prevents breaking the code.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to deal with this in the past too, where you can't be certain that the field with be in the same column because the source table has changed.
If you would always have the same field header (column header) then you can use the code I've used before.

```
Public Function FindColumn(ws As Worksheet, name As String, Optional headerRow As Integer = 1) As Integer

    On Error GoTo FUNC_ERR

    Dim sRng As Range: Set sRng = ws.Rows(headerRow).Find(what:=name, _
                                                          LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                          lookat:=xlWhole)
    If sRng Is Nothing Then
        'Handle if not found
    Else
        FindColumn = sRng.Column
    End If

FUNC_EXIT:
    Exit Function

FUNC_ERR:
    'Handle error

End Function
```

HeaderRow is optional and assumed to be row 1, but you can also call out a different row if necessary.

Then instead of using the column letter in the `.cell()` callout, you can use the returned column number.

```
dim columnNumber as Integer: columnNumber = FindColumn(ccarWks, "Header Name")
With ccarWks    
    With .Cells(nextRow, columnNumber) 
        .Value = Now
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss" 
    End With

    '...more code...
End With
```

Hope this helps you.